# Issue with json extraction key value

Tags: json, devops, jq, influxdb, telegraf

I  have this jq to work with another json file somehow is not picking this up based on key and value. I would like to get the status of each value either UP or DOWN for each key. The code is below:

```
  curl -s http://example:8080/external_indicator | jq -r '
  to_entries[] | select(.value | type == "object")
  | [.key, .value.components.status] as [$id, $status]
  | "app_custom,\($id=\($status) wlb_status_code=\(["DOWN","UP"] | index($status))"
'
```

Desired output should be:

```
                  app_custom,db=UP status_code=1
                  app_custom,angleDS=UP status_code=1
                  app_custom,argosleDS=UP status_code=1
```

But current output is :

```
app_custom,components_status=null status_code=null
```

Json file is

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "components": {
        "DS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 194
          }
        },
        "angusDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 166
          }
        },
        "argyleDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 155
          }
        },
        "ayrDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 166
          }
        },
        "banffDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 156
          }
        },
        "caithnessDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 156
          }
        },
        "clackmannanDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 155
          }
        },
        "DS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "H2",
            "validationQuery": "isValid()"
          }
        },
        "dumbartonDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 155
          }
        },
        "eastLothianDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 168
          }
        },
        "fifeDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 166
          }
        },
        "glasgowDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 171
          }
        },
        "invernessDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 166
          }
        },
        "kirkcudbrightDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 166
          }
        },
        "lanarkDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 159
          }
        },
        "midLothianDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 157
          }
        },
        "morayDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 156
          }
        },
        "orkneyDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 156
          }
        },
        "perthDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 169
          }
        },
        "renfrewDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 167
          }
        },
        "adesDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 156
          }
        },
        "stirlingDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 157
          }
        },
        "sutherlandDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 156
          }
        },
        "westLothianDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Informix Dynamic Server",
            "validationQuery": "select count(1) from systables",
            "result": 155
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "discoveryComposite": {
      "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
      "status": "UNKNOWN",
      "components": {
        "discoveryClient": {
          "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
          "status": "UNKNOWN"
        }
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 128300593152,
        "free": 37138010112,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "livenessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "rabbit": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "version": "3.7.28"
      }
    },
    "readinessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "refreshScope": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  },
  "groups": [
    "liveness",
    "readiness"
  ]
}
```

How would I be able to extract the key and get it based on this output

```
              app_custom,db=UP status_code=1
              app_custom,angleDS=UP status_code=1
              app_custom,argosleDS=UP status_code=1
```

Comment: the JSON file is invalid

Comment: the jq expression does not compile: `1 compile error`

Comment: @jpseng updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter does not match up with the structure of your input. Your input has a recursive structure and your filter is only looking at the top level. The status is on the children of each component object so `.value.components.status` is incorrect.

I'm not sure what exactly your goal is but since this is recursive, you could use `..` to descend through the tree and filter objects that have a `components` property and pick values to display.

```
$ curl -s ... | jq -r '
.. | .components? // empty | to_entries[]
    | [.key, .value.status] as [$id, $status]
    | "app_custom,\($id)=\($status) status_code=\(if $status=="UP" then 1 else 0 end)"
'
app_custom,db=UP status_code=1
app_custom,discoveryComposite=UNKNOWN status_code=0
app_custom,diskSpace=UP status_code=1
app_custom,livenessState=UP status_code=1
app_custom,ping=UP status_code=1
app_custom,rabbit=UP status_code=1
app_custom,readinessState=UP status_code=1
app_custom,refreshScope=UP status_code=1
app_custom,DS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,angusDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,argyleDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,ayrDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,banffDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,caithnessDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,clackmannanDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,dumbartonDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,eastLothianDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,fifeDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,glasgowDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,invernessDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,kirkcudbrightDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,lanarkDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,midLothianDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,morayDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,orkneyDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,perthDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,renfrewDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,adesDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,stirlingDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,sutherlandDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,westLothianDS=UP status_code=1
app_custom,discoveryClient=UNKNOWN status_code=0
```

Here it is written a bit differently to hopefully illustrate what part is doing what.

```
..                                            # recurse through the object tree
  | .components? // empty                     # get the components object or skip if none
  | to_entries[]                              # convert the object to entries
  | [.key, .value.status] as [$id, $status]   # bind $id and $status variables
  | ($id | gsub(" +"; "_")) as $fixedId       # replace spaces in id with underscores
  | (if $status=="UP" then 1 else 0 end) as $statusCode             # set statusCode to 1 if $status is "UP"
  | "app_custom,\($fixedId)=\($status) status_code=\($statusCode)"  # construct the final string given the components above
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff Mercado. what if the key as space and I do not want it to have space. One of the key for example has space Simple Reactive Discovery Client=UP.  It works but soehow now having issue passing through telegraf.  Can I assign it in that jq to not have space as the $id in the variable

Comment: I would want a Simple_Reactive_Discovery_Client rather than having space in the keys. anyhow to manipulate that ??

Comment: You could use something like `gsub` to replace the spaces with whatever character you want (`_` in your case). Apply it to the id. `$id | gsub(" +"; "_")`

Comment: do you mean to change this part  \($id)=\($status) to $id | gsub(" "; "_")=\($status).

Comment: It is giving error unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 4:
  | "app_custom,\($id) | gsub(" +"; "_")=\($status)

Comment: And I applied it in anpther place, like this syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ',' or ']' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 3:
  | [.key, .value.status] as [$id | gsub(" +"; "_"), $status]

Comment: I'd say, pay attention to the syntax. We're using string interpolation to build up the final string. The `\()` in the string is important otherwise it won't work as intended. Just throwing things around hoping it would stick would not do it.